# Inline JavaFX CSS has troubles with properties

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-css

I have a `LineChart` and I want to change the `-fx-background-color` of its `-chart-plot-background` property. I want to do it **without** using an **external** CSS file (and only through the code, since I want to be able to change a property dynamically). Unfortunately, the following lines fail to work:

```
linechart.setStyle("-chart-plot-background(-fx-background-color: red;)");

linechart.setStyle("-chart-plot-background{-fx-background-color: red;}");
```

The error reads:

```
Jun 21, 2023 7:04:17 PM javafx.css.CssParser parse
WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-chart-plot-background(-fx-background-color: red;)}: Expected RBRACE at [1,45]
```

or

```
Jun 21, 2023 7:04:17 PM javafx.css.CssParser parse
WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-chart-plot-background{-fx-background-color: red;}}: Expected RBRACE at [1,45]
```

How can we tackle this problem?

Comment: I don't know why an external CSS file would not work for this case.  When you want the red state, you could add an additional styleclass to the chart and have CSS rules that set the red background when that styleclass is applied to the chart.  When you don't want the red state anymore, you could remove the red styleclass.  If needed, the required style sheets can be [generated in code from a template using a data URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76375731/changing-styles-of-individual-lines-drawn-in-javafx/76383545#76383545).

Answer (score 3):

The string you pass to `setStyle()` should be a syntactically valid CSS rule, or set of rules separated by `;`. The text you are passing is not the correct syntax.

> I want to do it without using an external CSS file ... since I want to be able to change a property dynamically

You can use external CSS and change colors dynamically using "looked-up colors" (see the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) for a definition). In brief, do:

```
.chart {
    -plot-background-color: red;
}
.chart .chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-color: -plot-background-color;
}
```

and then you can change it dynamically with

```
linechart.setStyle("-plot-background-color: blue;");
```

---

Depending on your use-case, a custom pseudoclass may also be appropriate. This would also allow you to change properties other than colors dynamically. For the specific example you posted:

```
.chart:alert .chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

and then in code you can do

```
private final PseudoClass alertPC = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("alert");

// ...

linechart.pseudoClassStateChanged(alertPC, true); // will make background red

// ...

linechart.pseudoClassStateChanged(alertPC, false); // restores default background
```

---

As pointed out in a comment, both of these approaches have limitations. The "looked-up color" approach can only be used for colors (JavaFX CSS does not support other types of CSS variable), and custom CSS PseudoClasses can only be used for a discrete set of values.

As a last resort, for use-cases that do not fit into those two, you can use a [CSS lookup](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup(java.lang.String)). Note that the `lookup(...)` method will return null unless a CSS pass has been made, but since you are dynamically applying these styles, this should have happened at the point you need to apply the dynamic style. Again, for the example you cite:

```
Node plotBackground = linechart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
plotBackground.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
```

If for any reason you need to do this *before* the chart has CSS applied in the natural lifecycle of the scene graph (this really shouldn't happen; your external CSS (or just the system default) can define the initial/default CSS state, and the dynamic changes should only be invoked after some event occurs, which should necessarily be after the component is displayed), you can force CSS to be applied via calls to `linechart.applyCSS();` and `linechart.layout();`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, numeric properties cannot be set dynamically through defining variables, and using pseudoclasses seems to have so many limits (for example, you cannot change the legend font size or plot background color dynamically over any set of values).

Comment: @KeenTeen That is correct; for use cases that fall outside of those supported by looked-up colors or pseudoclasses, you will have to use a CSS lookup. See update to answer.